# React-native not install apk in android

Tags: android, mobile, react-native, react-native-ios

React-Native Run-android
Was Not Install Apk. In Device
Show Only Build Successfully but apk does not install in device

Screen Shot:

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have USB debugging mode On in your device Other wise you can install from (diawi.com ) link

Comment: Enable USB Debugging on Developer Options

Comment: adb devices show my devices and debugging also on USB also connected properly but don't know why it was not installed @Madhur and @ Akila

Comment: From the screenshot, it looks like the app has been installed successfully. Go and check the app drawer if your app exists or check settings => apps => search for your app. Maybe some app permissions are disabled for the app.